# Flocker: How do I provide a custom /etc/mongodb.conf file?

Tags: docker

I've followed the ["Deploying and migrating a multi-node ElasticSearch-Logstash-Kibana cluster using Docker"](https://clusterhq.com/2014/10/14/deploying-multi-node-elasticsearch-logstash-kibana-cluster-using-docker/) tutorial.
I've also added MongoDB to it. So far, so great.

However I need to install some Elasticsearch plugins and run some curl commands to get things working.

Where should I put these commands that install plugins for ES?

```
$ plugin --install com.github.richardwilly98.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-river-mongodb/2.0.9
$ plugin --install elasticsearch/elasticsearch-mapper-attachments/2.5.0
```

Notify ES about the mongodb river

```
$ curl -XPUT 'http://172.16.255.250:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d @init.json
```

I have created a repo with what I got so far: https://github.com/soldotno/flocker-harvester#wishlist
My first thought is that it would be nice if I could put `mongodb.yml` in the root directory and somehow copy it to the docker container using `ADD`.

Please advice me on how to get this working. :-)

Cheers,
Martin